# How to integrate $\phi(x) = ce^{-\frac{1}{1 - |x|^2}}$ for $c > 0$ and $|x| < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm reading an analysis book and the author considers the function $\phi(x) = ce^{-\frac{1}{1 - |x|^2}}$ for $|x| < 1$ and $\phi(x) = 0$ for $|x| > 1$. Here $c > 0$ is a constant.

He claims this function is smooth on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the constant $c$ can be chosen so its integral is equal to $1$.

How can we evaluate the integral of the function $\phi(x)$?

If someone can also explain how we can show its smooth I will appreciate that.

Comment: All its derivatives at $x=\pm 1$ are zero. That's why it's smooth. And you don't have to evaluate the integral. The point is that it exists. If $\psi = \phi$ with $c=1$ and $a := \int\psi(x)\,dx$, then $\int\phi\,dx = c\int\psi\,dx = ca$. Hence, if $c = 1/a$, then $\int\phi\,dx = 1$.